# PHP Post PDO Smarty does not function the same

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Can someone explain to me why after incorporating PDO into my code the way I call Smarty has changed? For instance I am receiving lots of errors because Smarty is not functioning post PDO.

Example Pre-PDO that worked:

```
{assign var='udatas' value="{$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>{$ststres[ststval].to_id}))}"}

 <span class="box-commnt-laps">{insert_time_dif({$ststres[ststval].added_date})} ago</span>
```

Example Post-PDO now works:

```
{assign var='udatas' value="$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))"}

<span class="box-commnt-laps">{insert_time_dif($ststres[ststval].added_date)} ago</span>
```

I can't seem to find any references on the net how I used structure smarty Post-PDO. Can you please point me in the right direction or explain why this happens and how to resolve?

Comment: Did anything else change, like your Smarty version? It seems unlikely that this has anything to do with PDO.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski no nothing changed. I just incorporated PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer Update:

Is to add [] between the associative array and remove the quotes like so.

```
{assign var='brgdatas' value=$brgObj->fetchOneBrg(['id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id])}
```

Answer (score 0):

dude. I don't know too much of the new smarty but in the old one it was like this:

```
{assign var='udatas' value=$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>{$ststres[ststval].to_id}))}
```

You don't have to add `"` to value in assign